# Entity Framework many-to-many for three or more tables

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

Is it possible to create a bridge table for three or more tables with EF Code First?

```
User      Role      Node
+UserId   +RoleId   +NodeId
+Name     +Name     +Name

UserRoleNode
+UserId
+RoleId
+NodeId
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
I made an entity for the bridge table and then I made one-to-many connections between UserRoleNode and the other tables. Hm?

Comment: Shared Primarykey. Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is possible with the Fluent API, too?